# Generate video in MATLAB from png generated from R

Tags: r, matlab, ggplot2

I have generated multiple .png plots in R using `ggplot` and I need to make a video of these plots. I am trying to use MATLAB for this purpose. I am able to generate the video but the quality is poor and no colors can be seen there in the video, although my .png files are colored. The `ggplot` command is shown below:

```
ggplot(vel1,aes(vel1[,1],vel1[,2],color=vel1[,14639])) +geom_point()+ scale_color_manual(breaks = c("8", "6", "4"), values=c("red", "blue", "green"))
```

The MATLAB code that I am using is:

```
writerObj = VideoWriter('1889_2121.avi');
writerObj.FrameRate=15;
open(writerObj);
for K = 1889:2:2121
  filename = sprintf('vel_cluster%d.png', K);
  thisimage = imread(filename);
  writeVideo(writerObj, thisimage);
end
close(writerObj);
```

You can get access to the sample .png files and video here [Sample Files for testing](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1X06TdYLDE6DNN5vO75HNSUEdO8dQgnXc). Could you please help me with this issue.

Comment: have you tried adding a specific profile to it? `VideoWriter('1889_2121.avi','Uncompressed AVI')`

Comment: Yes, I did. But it didn't work either.

Comment: I woudl suggest you make an animated gif instead.

Comment: As pointed out by @AnderBiguri, take a look at `gganimate` : [https://github.com/dgrtwo/gganimate](https://github.com/dgrtwo/gganimate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not open the corresponding colormap.

```
thisimage = imread(filename);
```

Returns to you the uint8 values of the pixels.

```
[thisimage,map] = imread(filename);
```

gives you the colormap to use.

```
frame.cdata=thisimage;frame.colormap=map;
writeVideo(writerObj, frame);
```

should do the trick.

But I agree with the commenters that gganimate should be more suited for what you want to do than Matlab.

Comment: Thank You, it worked. I shall also try gganimate @AnderBiguri